$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\#\{k_1^2+k_2^2+k_1k_2\in \mathbb{Z}\mid 0\le k_1,k_2\le n, ~k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{Z}\}}{n^2}$
I want to know the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)$ where $f(n):=\frac{\#\{k_1^2+k_2^2+k_1k_2\mid 0\le k_1,k_2\le n,~k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{Z}\}}{n^2}$.
By numerical experiments, this function for $n$ is almost decrease and more concretely,

$f(100)=0.3982, f(200)=0.3738, f(300)=0.3615..., f(400)=0.3536, f(500)=0.3477, f(600)=0.3431...$.


$f(1000)=0.331.., f(2000)=0.317..,f(3000)=0.310,\cdots, f(6000)=0.29881...$

Please help me, thanks.

I suspect the limit is 0 — the number of values representable as $a^2 + b^2$ grows like $n /\sqrt{\log n}$, and this is very similar — if you multiply your numbers by 4 they are representable by $(2k_1+k_2)^2 + 3k_2^2 = a^2 + 3b^2$. I think the relevant search term is "representation by quadratic form".
